# Custom 'String' Class 

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I'm trying to figure out how java classes work.

When I create a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder testString = new StringBuilder("Hello World!);
```

If I want to, say, get the value that `testSting` holds a reference to, I can simply call it like: `System.out.println(testString);`

This is cool behavior, but I'm unsure how to replicate it in classes that I make.

For instance, if I were to try and re-implement my own version of `StringBuilder`, the approach I would take (as a beginner), would be this:

```
class MyBuilder {
    char[] string; 


public MyBuilder(String s) {
    string = new char[s.length()];
    string = s.toCharArray();

}
```

So, to make the string an array I had to store it in a data field of the class. But then, to access this in my code, I can't print it by simply calling the variable name. I would have to use `.property` syntax. Thus, to duplicate the above example, I would have to type `System.out.println(testString.value);` Which isn't nearly as pretty.

How do you make a class such that it behaves like `String` or `StringBuilder` and returns its value without manually accessing the data fields?

Comment: Override `toString`. `PrintStream.println` merely does `toString` to determine the string representation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement a `toString` method.

[`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) is a method on `Object`, so every java object inherits one. The default implementation that you inherit is only useful for getting the class type, and for distinguishing one object from another; the format is: *ClassName@HashCode*. There are no details unique to your implementation.

In your own classes, to get the description that you want you'll need to override the `toString` method, so that in contexts where a `String` is expected, e.g. when you call `System.out.println(myObject.toString());`, your own format is used.

It's often a good idea to do this, for a more readable description of your object. You can always call `super.toString` to include the output from the default - *ClassName@HashCode* - in your own output.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `Object.toString()` in your object `MyBuilder`. System.out.println calls on this method for every object used. For example here, you could use:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   return Arrays.toString(string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the toString-Method

```
private String value;

public MyClass(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public String toString() {
    return value;
}
```